# HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: android, rest, video, upload

I want to a upload video through my android application with following code.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody input = new FileBody(file);
ContentBody name  = new StringBody("VID_20130201_162220.3gp");
ContentBody description = new StringBody("Test Description");
entity.addPart("input",input);
entity.addPart("name",name);
entity.addPart("description",description);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
```

When httpClient.execute() method returns the response, it shows "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type"

I have also tried removing the MultipartEntry from HttpPost but still it gives the same error.

can someone suggest me what could be the problem.

Comment: problem seems to be on the server side

Comment: an iphone application is using same service, so i dont think this could be a server issue...

Comment: inspect both requests (iphone and android) at the server level, and see what differs. the server is rejecting the request for a reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the server to allow the 3gp media type. If you're using Apache, you can do this by adding `AddType video/3gpp .3gp` to the server's configuration file. (I think that is the correct syntax).

Comment: I have tried this same code for .mp4 and .avi files as well. It thrown same error for these files

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: it works for most types of files.

```
private DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient;
Context context;
public String error = "";

//Contrutor para que metodos possam ser usados fora de uma activity
public HTTPconector(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public HTTPconector() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
}


public void FileClientPost(String txtUrl, File file){
    try
    {
        error = "";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(txtUrl);
        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(file));
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(HTTPconector.class.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        e.getStackTrace();
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
}

//Verifica se a rede esta disponível
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
    // otherwise check if we are connected
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String Get(String txtUrl){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(txtUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(10000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.connect();

        return readStream(con.getInputStream());

    }  catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
    }
}


public String Post(String txtUrl){
    File image;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(txtUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();

        //con.getOutputStream().write( ("name=" + "aa").getBytes());

        return readStream(con.getInputStream());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
    }
}


//Usado para fazer conexão com a internet
public String conectar(String u){
    String resultServer = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(u);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        resultServer = readStream(con.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resultServer = "ERRO: "+ e.getMessage();
    }

    Log.i("HTTPMANAGER: ", resultServer);
    return resultServer;
}

//Lê o resultado da conexão
private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    String serverResult = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        serverResult = reader.toString();
    }   catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        serverResult = "ERRO: "+ e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                serverResult = "ERRO: "+ e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    return  serverResult;
}

private class PhotoUploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Object>
{
    @Override
    public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        Log.d("UPLOAD", responseString);
        return null;
    }
}
```